Issue with quarkus ServerExceptionMapper
I'm trying to configure an exception to return a http 400: bad request with a custom message in quarkus.
By default a BAD_REQUEST returns without a message, and that is not what I want.
The exception I'm trying to get through
public class InvalidRowNumberException extends BadRequestException {
    public InvalidRowNumberException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}

The mapper I currently have. It uses NOT_FOUND for diagnostics. The actual code I get is BAD_REQUEST, so I know the mapper is not used. This should become BAD_REQUEST.
public class ExceptionMapperProvider {
    @ServerExceptionMapper
    public RestResponse<String> mapInvalidRowNumberExceptionException(InvalidRowNumberException e) {
        return RestResponse.status(RestResponse.Status.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
    }
}

Rest endpoint
@POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    String shootCannon(@Valid @NotNull Shot shot){
        if(shot.getCoordinate().getRowNumber() <= 0){
            throw new InvalidRowNumberException("Row number can't be negative");
        }
        return "HitOrMiss";
    }

I've tried to notate the Mapper class with an @Provider annotation, but that didn't work either.

Is ExceptionMapperProvider part of the application itself?

its included in the main codebase, if that is what you mean.

Bad request without any message tipically means there is an other issue (e.g. malformed json was passed) In my case I can reproduce this behaviour by passing  an invalid json (missing last closing bracket. According to  documentation stacktrace is not logged by default. In dev mode try to enable quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler".level=DEBUG
